# Android how to retrieve data from a Service using an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, service, extra

I have a location service running on a separate java:

```
public class GPSService extends Service implements LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    Intent intent;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    String lat, lon;
    public static String str_receiver = "servicetutorial.service.receiver";
```

I want to retrieve mLastLocation from it using an intent from another class, to pass that Location as input of the func MyFunc

If I use

```
startService(new Intent(this, GPSService.class));
GPSService obj = new GPSService ();
MyFunc(obj.mLastLocation);
```

It compiles, but the Location object passed is null

Do I need to use put and get Extras? How to use it in case of Location variable? I do need to use put as well?

Note: Service is working no problem and updating as designed.
Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use a broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass latitude and longitude as two different `double` values and retrieve using getDoubleExtra

Comment: Doesn't work , it is unable to locate lat and lon. Do I have to use putDoubleExtra on variable lat and lon before I can use getDoubleExtra on it?